# SASS + Compass with Gulp

Tags: sass, compass-sass, gulp

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly.

1. Gulp creates the sass file for the required compass mixins
2. which I then import into my sass
3. This sass file is then compiled by gulp.

So far I:

1. Installed `gulp-compas`s with `npm`
2. I imported the compass module which I need in my project and used the mixin in my SCSS file:

   ```
   @import "/compass/css3/box-shadow";

   #box-shadow-custom {
       @include box-shadow(red 2px 2px 10px); }
   }
   ```
3. **Here is where I'm getting confused, so where do I have to put it? Or do I even have to add a gulp task?** Because in the compass tutorial I did they just seemed to import it like a normal scss file.

   ```
   var gulp = require('gulp');
   var sass = require('gulp-sass');
   var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
   var rename = require('gulp-rename');
   var del = require('del');

   gulp.task('clean', function(){
       del(['../typo3/fileadmin/assets/css/2014-12-30-ag-style.min.css'],{'force':true})
   })

   gulp.task('sass', function () {
       gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
           .pipe(sass())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
       gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
           .pipe(sass())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('../typo3/fileadmin/assets/css/'));
   });

   gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
     gulp.src('./css/*.css')
       .pipe(minifyCSS({keepBreaks:true}))
       .pipe(rename("2014-12-30-ag-style.min.css"))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('../typo3/fileadmin/assets/css/'));
   });

   // Watch Files For Changes
   gulp.task('watch', function() {
       gulp.watch('./scss/*.scss', ['clean','sass']);
       gulp.watch('./css/*.css', ['minify-css']);
   });

   // Default Task
   gulp.task('default', ['clean','sass','minify-css','watch']);
   ```

Or do I install just the compass package with `npm`? But there is no `box-shadow.scss`.

Comment: You have a mistake in syntax `@include box-shadow(red 2px 2px 10px);}` *. Remove this `}`.

Comment: Oh thanks. But thats not solving it  I just deleted s.th. while copying it to the example here. The problem starts already before because "/compass/css3/box-shadow" does not exist.